# CodeIgniter shows unexpected errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter v1.0 to work on my PHP application. Yesterday, running it on localhost, things were okay, but today there are many errors showing up in CI's logs. Here are some examples:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: helpers/functions_helper.php
Line Number: 515
```

---

```
Severity: Warning
Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed
Filename: controllers/reports.php
Line Number: 102
```

---

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: carray
Filename: controllers/reports.php
Line Number: 103
```

---

What might be causing these errors to appear?

Comment: Posting your code would be helpful.. Add the reports.php controller code

Comment: did you just transfer your code to a different server? the errors have probably always been there but your level of error_reporting has most likely changed

Comment: why are you running version 1? why not upgrade to v2.1?

Answer (score 0):

First of all CodeIgniter 1 is really really old. You should upgrade to AT LEAST 2.1. I'd upgrade to [CodeIgniter 3](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter).

Eitherway, inside your index.php file, there is a line that looks like this probably

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You need to change it to

```
error_reporting(0);
```

When you go to production.